# jQuery refuses to work

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to get a simple jQuery example to work for several hours now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle</button>
<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to load the jQuery.

Comment: Best guess: you don't have a web server installed on your computer and you're loading the page from local filesystem, so the `//` in jQuery's address picks up the `file://` protocol. This would be a good time to learn how the browser's error console works so you can debug things like this yourself.

Comment: can you remove // in front of ajax.googleapis.com and then try

Comment: @Satya That will certainly not work.

Comment: @user1925923 who are you referring to as God, Juhana or the God :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably, you are running your html locally

try using `http:` in your jquery url like this -

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to missing the **http:** prefix on your script url :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

put `http:` when you include javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this line of code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Added the `https:` for the src.